# Firebase Google Sign In "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException sign_in_failed..."

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-signin

I know there's a lot of information around the web and I've read all the posts and articles I found on the web and still can't figure it out and google documentation about the errors is very bad. Many people complains about it but I don't see any obvious fix and most people are using debug and development mode to avoid this setup.

I've created a flutter app that needs to make Google Sign In and of course, it don't work.

1) I've created the firebase project, activated the android app project, placed the SHA1 release and the .json on the project.

2) I've followed the flutter docs to release the app (key.properties, changing the `signingConfigs` and that stuff. App it's not on the Play Store, I'm testing on my phone.

2.1) `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`

3) Flutter dependencies:

```
firebase_auth: 0.7.0
  google_sign_in: 3.2.4
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  fluttertoast: ^2.0.7
  image_picker: 0.4.12+1
  shared_preferences: 0.4.3
  firebase_storage: 1.0.4
  cached_network_image: ^0.7.0
  intl: ^0.15.7
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

4) I'm using the new `GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential` and not the old `SignInWithGoogle`

```
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
```

4.1) `Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.`

5) When I press login I get this errors:

```
E/flutter (23045): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
E/flutter (23045): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (23045): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter (23045): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23045): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:217:58)
E/flutter (23045): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23045): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:256:20)
E/flutter (23045): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:324:48)
E/flutter (23045): #5      _LoginScreenState._handleSignIn (package:flikmechat/login_signup.dart:69:57)
E/flutter (23045): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23045): #6      _LoginScreenState._loginPage.<anonymous closure> (package:flikmechat/login_signup.dart:566:52)
E/flutter (23045): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23045): #7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter (23045): #8      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter (23045): #9      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter (23045): #10     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter (23045): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:211:7)
E/flutter (23045): #12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (23045): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:225:20)
E/flutter (23045): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter (23045): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (23045): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (23045): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (23045): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (23045): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (23045): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (23045): #21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
E/flutter (23045): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
```

Please advise, I really don't know what to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by adding the Sha1 debug key on firebase.

I thought that placing the release Sha1 was enough but it's not since when we test on mobile it uses the apk debug.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty can go wrong, as I explained in my answer to this question: [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122520/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-co/56408243#56408243)

Make sure to have your [image: Public Setting Support Email] set in your firebase project settings: