# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

Before mark it as duplicate please read the question.

I have set both SHA1 and SHA256 in my google console.

[image]

I have tried many way but still facing error.

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Also tried with [Flutter and google_sign_in plugin: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google) and other so many.

Where I'm still missing ?

Comment: hi @Govaadiyo.. have you fix it?

Comment: @bCliks yes you have to do flutter clean, flutter doctor and then "invalidate cache/ restart" android studio.

Comment: Can we mark it duplicate after reading it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

A lot can go wrong and I struggled for a very long time to fix this issue. My fix was that I needed to select the support email address in the settings of my firebase project.

Good luck

Johan

[image: Support email]

Answer (score 1):

you can try to do a `flutter clean` to rebuild from 0 the project.
It works for me.