# Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null))

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using firebase for google authentication in my flutter app. I registered app in the firebase and set all configurations like adding SHA1 and SHA256 key, and all. However, I get the error:

```
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

    Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async{
      GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken
      );

      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      print("Sign In "+user.displayName);
      return user;
       }
```

It is needed to return user credentials. However, It throws following error.

```
    PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null))
```

As per the links [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122520/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-co), I have added my mail for mail support, added google-services.json file. However, that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: check if you google play services are up to date

Comment: Is it needed to have Play Service account with the payment of $25?

Comment: no. it is in your emulator

Comment: I am using physical android device. Can you give me the link to the app?