# FIrebase Google Auth not working in flutter :PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

Please before mark it as duplicate read all the details.
I get this error when working in firebase google sign in :

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

I add both SHA1 and SHA256 and support email and the internet connection permission and all what I found needed in docs, tutorials,Stacoverflow answer but still getting the above error.
also tried `flutter clean`,`invalidate cache/ restart` ,deleting the app ..

The amazing thing is when I tried Firebase `Email/password` Auth it worked fine but google auth isn't working !

Also tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122520/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-co),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122520/unhandled-exception-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-co)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter and google\_sign\_in plugin: PlatformException(sign\_in\_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557479/flutter-and-google-sign-in-plugin-platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google)

Answer (score 0):

- Create the build from the same system which SHA1 and SHA256 has been added to firebase
- Replace the google-services.json and google-services-info.plist files latest from firebase in case there are any changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).